# Bootstrap table. How to remove all borders from table?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

How to remove all (especially outer ones) borders from [bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)? Here is a table without inner borders:

**HTML**

```
<style>
    .table th, .table td { 
        border-top: none !important;
        border-left: none !important;
    }
</style>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <br/>
        <table data-toggle="table" data-striped="true">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E</td>
                <td>F</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</row>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sba7wkvb/1/

Which CSS styles need to be overriden to remove all borders?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this case you need to set the border **below the table** and the borders **around - table heade**r, **table data**, **table container** all to 0px in-order to totally get rid of all borders.

```css
.table {
    border-bottom:0px !important;
}
.table th, .table td {
    border: 1px !important;
}
.fixed-table-container {
    border:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <br/>
        <table data-toggle="table" data-striped="true">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E</td>
                <td>F</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using bootstrap this will help you:

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
```

Answer (score 4):

you can set classes option to table table-no-bordered, example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/no-bordered.html.

Edit: this feature is only supported in develop version(after v1.7.0): https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src.

Comment: It works but still appear two horizontal border lines - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sba7wkvb/2/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.table th, .table td {
    border-top: none !important;
    border-left: none !important;
}
.fixed-table-container {
    border:0px;
}
.table th {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
.table:last-child{
  border:none !important;
}
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ferrrmolina/sba7wkvb/6/)

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap
In html

```
<table class="table no-border">
```

In css

```
.table.no-border tr td, .table.no-border tr th {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Source: https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/ogVQqG

Answer (score 2):

Change the `border` size in the CSS for the `.fixed-table-container`

CSS:

```
.table th, .table td {
    border-top: none !important;
    border-left: none !important;
}
.fixed-table-container {
    border:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sba7wkvb/3/

Comment: `border-bottom: none !important;` removed one border from the rest two. But most bottom still there.

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<table class="table noborder">
```

css

```
.noborder td, .noborder th {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for remove outer border you should remove border from `.fixed-table-container` as follow :

```
.fixed-table-container{border: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set `border: none !important;` to `.fixed-table-container` **and** `.table`. Also set `border-bottom: none !important;` to your first rule, `.table th, .table td`.
Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sba7wkvb/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Kindly add the below code in your CSS sheet.It will remove all the borders in the table

```
.table th, .table td, .table {
    border-top: none !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
.fixed-table-container {
    border:0px;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

**Hope helped**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSS3 this will help you:

```
.table tbody tr td, .table tbody tr th {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `.table thead tr th` for the header

Comment: Yes, This removes all the borders for a table like this: <table class="table">